# Add column (with values) while writing to csv using csv.DictWriter in python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, yaml

I have a yml file as follows:

```
Stocks:
 - name: shop1
   apples: 100
   mangoes: 200

 - name: shop2
   apples: 20
   mangoes: 50
   bananas: 100
   garbage: 'something'
```

I want to create a tsv (or csv or pandas dataframe) file which looks as follows:

```
name    category  apples   mangoes   bananas
shop1   fruits    100      200       0
shop2   fruits    20       50        100
```

My code at the moment is as follows:

```
import yaml, csv

csv_columns = ['name','apples','mangoes','bananas', 'category']

with open('fruits.yml', 'r') as f:
    doc = yaml.load(f)


csv_file = "somename.csv"
try:
    with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns, extrasaction='ignore')
        writer.writeheader()
   for item in doc["Stocks"]:
        item.update( {"category":"fruits"})
   for data in doc["Stocks"]:
            writer.writerow(data)
except IOError:
    print("I/O error")
```

Works fine except that **I don't know the correct or elegant way** to add the column `category` with same value repeated over the rows. That value is actually the name of the yaml file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension while writing the data row as following.

```
for data in doc["websites"]:
    writer.writerow([data[0], "fruits"]+data[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need, in repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/MellowDisfiguredGroupware

Let me explain:

First you need to change `csv_columns`

```
csv_columns = ['name','category','apples','mangoes','bananas']
```

Second, based on the yaml you gave, there is no key `websites` in the `doc` dictionary, just a `Stocks` key. I have edited the writing part accordingly.

Third, you need to add the `category` key with the value `fruits`:

```
    try:
    with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns, extrasaction='ignore')
        writer.writeheader()
        for data in doc["Stocks"]:
            data['category'] = 'fruits'
            writer.writerow(data)
except IOError:
    print("I/O error")
```